# How to rename materialized view in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

How to rename math view in ClickHouse?

```
:) ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW db.table_1 RENAME TO db.table_2;
Syntax error: failed at position 7


:) RENAME MATERIALIZED VIEW db.table_1 TO db.table_2;
Syntax error: failed at position 8

:) RENAME TABLE db.table_1 TO db.table_2;

RENAME TABLE table_1 TO table_2
Received exception from server (version 19.4.4):
Code: 48. DB::Exception: Received from 127.0.0.1:9000. DB::Exception: Method rename is not supported by storage MaterializedView
```

Help me please!

Comment: I just tested this RENAME TABLE table_1 TO table_2. It worked.

Comment: specify client and server versions. It may help. I can see server is 19.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for renaming MaterializedView was added in the following version. 
**ClickHouse release 19.8.3.8, 2019-06-11**

Pull Request: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/5209

Answer (score 1):

How to convert not replicated MV to replicated
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/80cb95e74f046be2d8ffae58d9b04e8f

How to alter MV
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/431010ca08b9e51b960e55344b1dbbe3

MV_poplulating_with_freeze
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/64c05be67ef8a926242011188ce96f44

Several_MV_one_internal_store
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/005633470c70877dd28c00211cd9fcfb

Populate AggregatingMergeTree through null table 
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/f7382cd4f1f859ff6ac46afe7dc9925a

alter_MV_with_SummingMergeTree
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/3a8d57253711e277b2a60a75b5dfeef6

Rename MV in CH before 19.8.3.8 
https://gist.github.com/den-crane/d9a0bceb58a7d5314ea66e8edbebc9f7

Answer (score 1):

After ClickHouse release 19.8.3.8 ([reference](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/5209))

```
RENAME TABLE materialized_view_table TO materialized_view_table_migrate;
```

Before ClickHouse release 19.8.3.8 ([gist](https://gist.github.com/den-crane/d9a0bceb58a7d5314ea66e8edbebc9f7))

```
DETACH TABLE materialized_view_table;
RENAME TABLE `.inner.materialized_view_table` TO `.inner.materialized_view_table_migrate`;
```

rename .sql file and edit (using vi) `/var/lib/clickhouse/metadata/default/materialized_view_table.sql`

```
ATTACH TABLE materialized_view_table_migrate
```